# In what conditions can a DC isolated power supply generate a higher voltage at the flyback transformer's secondary side?

Tags: voltage, power, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, isolated

We have designed a passive PoE isolated power supply using a [TOP268](https://www.power.com/design-support/data-sheets/topswitch-jx-data-sheet) converter.

[image]

[image]

[image]

We are converting 48 V DC PoE input to 12 V/1 A output. This 12 V output we are feeding to a step-down power regulator [TPS563249DDC](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tps563249) to convert to 5 V and 1.1 V output voltages.

We observed that these DC-DC converters (TPS563249DDC) are getting damaged after one month of operation; Vin, SW, and GND ins are shorted.

Once we replace this faulty IC with a fresh one, the device starts working well again.

We have done the below-mentioned multiple experiments to see whether this failure can be reproduced in the lab or not, but we are unable to fail this switcher in the lab environment.

Test case 1: We have probed 1V1 and 12V rails at the full load condition to check any spike observation at the 12V rail.

TEST CASE 2: We have probed 5V and 12V rails at the full load condition to check any spike observation at the 12V rail.

TEST CASE 3: We have checked the power-up and power-down sequence to check if is there any spike generated.

TEST CASE 4: We have put one device with 70°C ambient with maximum load condition and the device is working fine.

TEST CASE 5: Put 8 devices for the long run test by rebooting them using the remote power supply.

TEST CASE 6: Powered ON 4 devices by the battery power supply and monitored the behavior.

TEST CASE 7: Put a variable load at the 12 V output to see if any spike/peak is being generated or not.

TEST CASE 8: EFT test to see if any spike/peak is generated at the PoE output (12 V).

TEST CASE 9: 1.1 V power regulator behavior at different load conditions, measured SW node along with 1.1 V power rail.

Please suggest what can go wrong which can lead to this TI DC/DC converter damage.

Comment: Welcome! Please post your layout.

Comment: Mohit - Hi, As well as posting the PCB layout, as kindly requested above, please add more context & your analysis so far (if any) about the distribution of failures. For example (not a full list): Are both 5V & 1.1V TI ICs failing? What proportion of each is failing across (a) whole population (b) on same board? Are they really specifically after "one month" of operation? I expect you didn't mean that, but instead you meant something else - perhaps first failures started after a month? Or most failures happen after one month? Think: Is this really POH, or number of cycles of something or ...?

Comment: Hi Sam, This TI switcher failure starts after one month of deployment. Some devices are working for the last 3 months and some failed within 1 month. The failure rate is approx 15% of the whole deployment.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot fewer compensation parts in the feedback circuit compared to the reference designs [Fig 26](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/328/topjx_family_datasheet-1511822.pdf).

I would suspect instability in the TOP268 regulator under some combination of line and load.

You can test various combinations of line and load with step changes (and over temperature) to see if there is any over/undershoot that indicates marginal stability.

Answer (score 0):

> *Please suggest what can go wrong which can lead to this TI DC/DC
> converter damage.*

In two words; **line surges**.

Think about a regular ethernet connection without PoE; they have magnetic line interfaces that typically provide 2 kV isolation and sometimes up to 6 kV againsy indirect lightning strikes.

Is T1 in your 48-volt-to-12-volt flyback converter circuit rated for this type of isolation? Might it be passing-on line surges via it's poor primary-secondary breakdown specification?

There may be other mechanisms with PoE such as inadvertent (or deliberate) earthing of your regulator outputs that can make things worse.

Comment: Hi Andy, To replicate this line surge in the lab we tried to feed from 0.5KV to 6KV at PoE Input Port in both differential as well as in common modes. But we were not able to see any peak or spike on the secondary side of the flyback transformer. T1 is having 1.5KV Isolation.

Comment: What type of surge waveform did you replicate? What are your loads on the regulators? Are they local? Do they make connections to earth? Were failures occurring at times when lightning storms were present?